# (SwiftUI) Google Maps Works Fine When Hitting "Play" But Doesn't Work On Side Preview

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I hit the "play" button, the phone emulator pops up and it shows google maps with my annotations.

[image: iPhone Emulator from "Play" Button]

However, it will not show on the side preview of SwiftUI.

[image: Side Preview]

I get the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'"

I have followed Google Maps "Getting Started" and have have provided the key but I'm still experiencing this error.

Here is rest of my code:

```
struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()

func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true

    do {

      if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
        mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
      } else {
        NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
      }
    } catch {
      NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }


    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Self.Context) {

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

//App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyAPIKey")
    return true
}

// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}
```

What can I do to fix the side preview? Thanks

Comment: AppDelegate methods are called by the application when it runs. The Preview window doesn’t run the whole application so you’ll need to call the Google Maps initialization function in your preview struct, maybe in init.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I just tried "init(){
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyKey")}" under GoogleMapView but it's the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Try putting API Key in `makeUIView`, like below:

```
func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyAPIKey")
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true

    do {

      if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
        mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
      } else {
        NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
      }
     } catch {
       NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }


    return mapView
}
```

Comment: Works! Enhanced by  ````#if DEBUG 
         GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleAPIKey)
        #endif````  Live Preview still not possible

Answer (score 0):

Put it into `PreviewProvider`, like below

```
struct GoogleMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyAPIKey")
        GoogleMapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried it and then got: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x117dfff28'

Answer (score 0):

You just want API Key in `makeUIView`. Bellow I mentioned.

```
 func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(APIKey)
}
```