# NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to show google maps in preview phone(SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to use the Google Maps iOS SDK on SwiftUI.

I'm getting the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x117dfff28'

I added this code in the preview struct to try and get rid of another error:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
    return ContentView()
}
```

Here is original question:
[(SwiftUI) Google Maps Works Fine When Hitting "Play" But Doesn't Work On Side Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552847/swiftui-google-maps-works-fine-when-hitting-play-but-doesnt-work-on-side-pr)

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.